# How to convert a column in pandas data frame as Time object

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv file with the date and jobs runtime values, I need to convert the object to time format.
Time value will be as follows:

```
00:04:23
00:04:25

pd.to_datetime(df[‘Time’], format=‘%H:%M:%S:’)
```

This returns the value with default date

```
1900-01-01 00:04:23
1900-01-01 00:04:25
```

How do I retain only the runtime as time data type in the column without date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make use of `to_timedelta` function in `pandas`.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
```

It will create time format of `timedelta64[ns]

Comment: Thanks timedelta works as per my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.Series.dt.time()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) to access time part.

```py
print(pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time)

'''
0    00:04:23
1    00:04:25
Name: Time, dtype: object
'''
```